# Redirect user to previous page after registration

Tags: 8, users, redirection

I'd like users registering on my website are redirected to the page where they clicked the "create account" button which is in a modal.

First, I tried to redirect to an absolute url
I tried

```
$form_state->setRedirect($myUrl);
```

I tried

```
$_REQUEST['destination'] = '<front>';
```

I tried this too :

```
$response = new \Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse('http://www.google.be');
$form_state->setResponse($response);
```

I'm always redirected to /user/[uid]/edit

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to achieve that..

Comment: Does Rules module allow to go to the previous page ?

Comment: A page redirect can be done to "a drupal path, path alias or external URL"

Comment: @dharma true for D7, but I would really, really, repeat really, want to see an improved version of your answer that explains HOW to do this with Rules in D8 ...

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with the [Rules Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_link) module, and using the php variable php variables %server[HTTP_REFERER]

Or, without having to enable php in rules, you can use a custom 'previous page' token, explained in [this drupal.org issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2021969#comment-10717514).

Create a rule that triggers when the link is clicked, stores the previous page a a variable, do some other actions you want and at the end a redirect action to that previous page variable.